# Update tag in page, when user changes his selection, with PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, var

I need to update a post image, whenever user changes his selection in a "select html tag".

I'm trying to use jQuery and php in order to do that.

I need to get the id of the option the user selected.

than i want to use this id to get an image url (using a wordpress function).

finally, i'd like to add this "url" in an image tag.

this is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#select2').select2();

        $('#select2').on('change', function() {
            var country = $('#select2 option:selected').val();
            <?php
            $the_id = 'I NEED HERE ID BY SELCETING IN DROPDPWN';
            $url=wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($the_id));
            ?>
            $(".countryvalue").html('<img width="80px" src="<?php echo $url; ?>" />');
        });

    });
</script>

<div class="countryvalue" ></div>

<select id="select2" name="marv_the_author">
      <option value="0">--Select author--</option>
      <option value="100">test</option>
      <option value="101">eeeee</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you should use ajax for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ajax for that.
change your jquery function to send an ajax call,
and create a php page for proccessing that call and sending back the proper url.

Your jquery function (notice this page has no php script on it, you can leave it to be a simple HTML page):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select2').on('change', function() {
        var country = $('#select2 option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({url: "getImageUrl.php?id=" + country,
                success: function(result){
                    $(".countryvalue").html('<img width="80px" src="' + result + '" />');              
        }});
    });
});
```

Create different php page like this:

```
<?php
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"];
    $url=wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($id));
    echo $url;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I do not need reload page i want show image in same page

Comment: this is what ajax does, i suggest you read about this. check this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp and this: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax. ajax doesn't reload the page again. it only changes page content, by calling other pages dynamically.

Comment: i fixed to jquery script so try it again. if not working, try these steps and let me know where you get stack:  1. browse to: `http://your_local_host/getImageUrl.php?id=123` . do you get "123" on the page?.    2. after `var country = $...` add this line: `alert(country); console.log(country);`. do you get anything?.    3.change the `success: function(result)` body from: `$(".countryvalue").html('<img width="80px" src="' + result+ .'" />');` to: `alert(result); console.log(result);`. do you get anything?

Comment: I try it: 1- yes get value after i add this echo $id = $_REQUEST["id"]; ..... 2 not get anything ..... 3 not get anything .... thanks

Comment: if i remove this $.ajax({url: "getImageUrl.php?id=" + country,
                                success: function(result){
                                    $(".countryvalue").html('<img width="80px" src="' + result + .'" />');
                                    alert(result); console.log(result);
                                });
                             });   ...... work the point 2 in alert ..

Comment: 1. does the `echo $url` line work with a real "id"? be sure to also check that. 2-3. try this instead and tell me if it works: `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select2').on('change', function() {
        var country = $('#select2 option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({url: "getImageUrl.php?id=" + country,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result); console.log(result);            
        }});
    });
}); `

Comment: work it is fain but this not woking... $(".countryvalue").html('<img width="80px" src="' + result + .'" />');

Comment: Drop the "."  after result. Also, browse to that url (u said you get it when just invoke: `alert(result);`), and make sure u get the picture correctly